# Google Contacts list view other contacts

Tags: google-contacts

When I am checking google contacts from the Brave browser in OS X; I don't know whether it is system issue or browser issue or google Contact issue.

In the Google Contacts side panel There is **More > Other Contacts**
(final URL is https://contacts.google.com/other) which lists out all contacts ( almost 300) which actually do not have phone numbers, but an email address. So I want to select many contacts in one way to delete them, BUT the list view display is very broad in width so there can be 10-12 contacts visible in one time. And also this list view has no scroll bar and no option to customize the list view. (see image below)

[image: Google Contacts issue]

does anyone know how to change this list view?

Comment: this does not occur with chrome+google-contacts+windows - just an observation

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over the contact, you'll see the avatar/colored circle icon turn into a checkbox. Click the checkbox, and then at the top of the screen, you'll see a box next to "1 selected"...click that box to select ALL of your Other Contacts. Then, click the 3-dot menu over on the right side of the screen, and click Delete. The more contacts you have here, the longer it will take to clear them out, but it does work eventually. Good luck!